# React, how to get size of element immediately after update the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get element size after updating the props, so I tried to get it through componentDidUpdate(), but each time it returns 0 for me

I wrote a component that controlled by its father component, in father component, a statement of setState is called, to change my component's props.

Then, I want to get size of a div in my component immediately after the props changed, so I put my code in componentDidUpdate(), but both clientHeight and getBoundingClientRect() return 0, actually, its height and width are definitely not 0.

```
/*index.js*/
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class MyTL extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.root = this.refs.tl
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.props.t){
      // this.root = this.refs.tl   // I tried to get root here, but not worked
      console.log(this.root.clientHeight)
      console.log(this.root.getBoundingClientRect())
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className='tr_c', refs='tl'></div>
    )
}

/* style.less*/
.tr_c{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

I expected an console output '290px', but it gave me 0

Is it not possible to get size here? please help me.

Comment: would using an ID rather than a ref work for your purposes? you can use `document.getElementById`. I tried this and it worked for getting the height on componentDidUpdate

Comment: @BrooklinMyers shouldn't use `document.getElementById` in React component

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is triggering the `componentDidUpdate()`, but using `componentDidMount()` for a reference, I would structure your element ref like such:

```js
class MyTL extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tl = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.tl.current.getBoundingClientRect());
    console.log(this.tl.current.clientHeight);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='tr_c' ref={this.tl}>
        <p>Stuff</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyTL />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
.tr_c {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dzuwan13/

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your `div`

```
<div className='tr_c', refs='tl'></div>
```

It has no contents, so Width/Height will be equals 0.